# String or StringBuilder for SQL query

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am working on my project and now I am having doubts about SQL query; is it okay to put the whole query in the String or it is better practice to use StringBuilder even though the query is static (it doesn't contain any variable)

```
private void createTheExpectedData() throws SQLException {
        String query = "SELECT products.productname, orderdetails.quantityordered, orderdetails.priceEach "
                + "FROM orderdetails "
                + "INNER JOIN products "
                + "ON orderdetails.productcode = products.productcode";
        resultSet = db.testClassQuery(query);
```

Comment: Try and profile both. Do you see a difference? If yes, that's your answer. If not, that's an answer as well.

Comment: I think java compiler is smart enough to optimize usage of string **constants** without any action from your side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They would be equivalent here, because Java performs `String` concatenation with `StringBuilder` (since Java 5 anyway). **However**, since the query is static I **would** suggest moving it to a `static` constant. Then you really don't have to worry if that concatenation takes too much time. Or about creating that temp `String` instance on every invocation.

```
private static final String CREATE_QUERY = "SELECT products.productname, "
            + "orderdetails.quantityordered, orderdetails.priceEach "
            + "FROM orderdetails "
            + "INNER JOIN products "
            + "ON orderdetails.productcode = products.productcode";

private void createTheExpectedData() throws SQLException {
    resultSet = db.testClassQuery(CREATE_QUERY);
    // ...
}
```